# Pandas, не получается выполнить проверку по двум столбцам

Tags: python, pandas

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Пытаюсь проверить данные по двум столбцам, допустим `Time = 0` и `Type = 0` одновременно, но получаю `NaN`.

```
Td = hor_df.loc[(hor_df['Time'] == '0') & (hor_df['Type'] == '0')]
Td.mean(numeric_only=True)
```

> https://mega.nz/file/3JZA1apY#IGi1mjNNPfHFxPxfevt_HdEAyr8bn3SlHuYkQGfGfcY

Comment: А вы уверены, что у вас в данных есть строки, для которых выполняются оба условия **одновременно**? Кроме того, я не уверен, что именно покажет `mean`, если в ещё каком-то **другом** столбце данных окажется `NaN`.

Comment: Я потестил, у меня `NaN` получается только в случае, если нет таких строк, что оба условия выполняются одновременно. Да, и ещё странно, что вы проверяете на **строку** равную нулю, а потом считаете среднее из этих строк. В случае, если у вас там смешанные данные - числа вперемешку со строками - то `mean` может такое показывать. Вы разберитесь - у вас числа в данных или строки, и что вы ищете собственно, строки или числа?

Comment: У меня есть таблица:
субъект/время/тип/тестостерон
MR01/0/0/12
MR02/0/0/15.7
...
PK16/1/152
И её мне требуется переделать в 
Subject| Testosterone_Time0_Type0| Testosterone_Time_1_type0| Testosterone_Time0_Type1| Testosterone_Time_1_type1|

Comment: Для этого я ищу строки с Time = 0 и Type = 0. Только я до сих пор не совсем понял как это бы оформить. У меня с pivottable получилась вертикальная, а тут будто бы хотят горизонтальную

Comment: Вообще такие вопросы без приложения примера данных к вопросу по правилам не отвечают )

Comment: Пытался приложить файл, если честно - не разобрался. Сайт принимает scv?

Comment: По-моему файлы нужно на какую-то файловую шару выкладывать. На яндекс диск или ещё как-то так.

Comment: А, ну кавычки просто уберите у нулей. Там у вас не строки, а числа. Но и результат будет - эти самые нули же.

Comment: Хорошо, а если я хочу найти среднее из всех, у кого Time = 0 и Type = 0, а затем поместить это среднее в ячейку Time0Type0, как я должен это сделать?

Comment: Среднее по каким колонкам то? Если по этим, то будет же ноль )

Comment: Среднее по колонкам тестостерон. Я беру строку с Time = 0, Type = 0, и беру это значение Testosterone. Затем я так складываю со всеми, пока не получу либо Time = 1, либо Type = 1. Из всех просуммированных Time0Type0 я беру среднее и кладу в Testosterone_Time0_Type0

Comment: Вам нужна фильтрация столбцов ?

Comment: В `Testosterone` у вас есть одно пробельное значение, из-за этого этот столбец не получился числовым и среднее по нему не показывается. Его нужно заменить на 0 например

Comment: Мне нужно:
Для значений Type0 Time0 просуммировать их тестостерон и среднее значение положить в ячейку Testosterone_TestosteroneType0Time0. Точно также сделать для Testosterone)Type0Time1 и т.д. И потом сделать таблицу: Субъекты/Testosterone_Type0Time0/.../Testosterone_Type0Time0

Comment: `tabl = pd.pivot_table(hor_df,
                            index = ['Subjects','Time0Type0','Time0Type1','Time1Type0','Time1Type1'],
                            columns = ['Time0Type0','Time0Type1','Time1Type0','Time1Type1']
                            )

tabl.dropna()`
вроде получилось, но как мне заполнить ячейки столбцов значениями?

Answer (score 0):

Как легко всех запутать, оказывается. Читаю ваш файл, причем - наипростейшим способом, что называется "по умолчанию" .

```
import pandas as pd
hor_df=pd.read_csv('horm_sort.csv')
```

Смотрю, а что-же за датафрейм такой я от вас получил:

```
hor_df.info()
```

и с большим удивлением обнаруживаю:

```
 0   Subjects      156 non-null    object 
 1   Time          156 non-null    int64  
 2   Type          156 non-null    int64  
 3   Testosterone  156 non-null    object 
 4   Cortisol      156 non-null    object
```

Теперь с еще большим удивлением смотрю в ваш код:

```
Td = hor_df.loc[(hor_df['Time'] == '0') & (hor_df['Type'] == '0')]
```

и возникает вопрос - а как так, данные, и стоблец Time и столбец Type имеют тип int64, а вы почему-то с ними пытаетесь работать как со строками. Непорядок! Исправляю - и все у меня работает. Что оно там считает - не знаю, но 39 каких-то строк в датафрейме Td формируется.

Что и как исправить -  оставляю на самостоятельную работу.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Ошибку понял как исправить, но это оказалось не совсем то, что мне было нужно. Если вас не затруднит - оставьте пожалуйста свои контактные данные, чтобы я мог вам задать вопросы!

Comment: Если вы исправили ошибку о которой спрашивали по моей подсказке, то на сайте это принято обозначать соответствующим образом (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Если у вас появился другой вопрос - задайте его в виде следующего вопроса на сайте, ведь сайт именно для этого и придуман.